# Send a SMS using Sinch (Android)

Tags: android, sinch

I am trying to send an SMS using Sinch but I am getting 404 and 500 errors from the server.

I read Sinch documentation and my code matches the examples. Is there something missing?

You can see my code below. It crashes when I'm trying to read the InputStream.

```
 public static boolean sendSMS(String message) {

        try {
            String phoneNumber = "00351961234567";
            URL url = new URL("https://messagingapi.sinch.com/v1/sms/ " + phoneNumber);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            String userCredentials = "application\\" + Constants.SINCH_APP_KEY + ":" + Constants.SINCH_APP_SECRET;

            byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(userCredentials.getBytes());
            String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(encoded);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);

            String postData = "{\"From\":\"00351913470050\" \"Message\":\"" + message + "\"}";
            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            os.write(postData.getBytes());
            int status = connection.getResponseCode();

            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
            String line;
            while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
                response.append(line);
            br.close();
            os.close();

            Log.i("SMS", response.toString());

            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: On Android Studio, in line  "InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());" it generates the exception FileNotFoundException

Comment: Can you post the message you're getting along with the error? Sometimes those are more specific, and it could be as simple as not having any money on your account to send SMS with.

Comment: I'm getting {"errorCode":40001,"message":"Country code PT is not whitelisted for messages"}. I sent an email to Sinch support because on their website they support Portugal communications so let's wait

Comment: Its working now right?

Comment: hello @cjensen i have also save issue with sinch send sms from app to phone it not working for me will you please tell how can i send sms from app to phone using sinch?

Answer (score 1):

All countries that we support are now whitelisted. And you should not have this problem

Comment: Hi cjensen!
The problem happened again only for 91 (Vodafone PT) numbers. I sent an email to Sinch Support.
The Receiver Phone doens't ring when a call is made